# Copy paste special VBA

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I'm a portuguese engineer and I've recently started programming in Visual Basic on a button from a specific Worksheet named "Início" on a Workbook named by "Livro MQTEN". On the Worksheet "Início" I have one button with the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim j As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim lngIndex As Long
Dim strPath() As String
Dim nome As String
Dim folha As String

' Open the file dialog
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Title = "Selecione o ficheiro dos comboios realizados do dia"
    .InitialFileName = "Explor. *"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    .Filters.Add "Excel files", "*.xlsx; *.xls", 1

    ' Display paths of each file selected
    For lngCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
        'MsgBox .SelectedItems(lngCount)
        j = .SelectedItems(lngCount)
        'MsgBox (j)

        strPath() = Split(j, "\")   'Put the Parts of our path into an array
        lngIndex = UBound(strPath)
        fileName = strPath(lngIndex)    'Get the File Name from our array

        'MsgBox (fileName)

        nome = fileName

        'Get name of sheet
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim TxtRng  As Range

        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        Set ws = wb.Sheets("Início")

        ws.Unprotect

        Set TxtRng = ws.Range("D17")
        TxtRng.Value = nome

        ws.Protect

        folha = Cells.Item(21, 6)

        'MsgBox (folha)

        'Copy from sheet

        Dim x As Workbook, y As Workbook
        Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
        Dim SrcRange As Range

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        Set x = Workbooks.Open(j)
        Set y = ThisWorkbook

        Set ws1 = x.Sheets(folha)
        Set ws2 = y.Sheets("Explor. do Mês")

        Set CopyData = ws1.Range("A1:M8000").EntireColumn
        CopyData.Copy
        Set Addme = ws2.Range("A1:M8000")
        Addme.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        x.Close True

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Next lngCount    
End With
End Sub
```

In the code:

```
Set CopyData = ws1.Range("A1:M8000").EntireColumn
CopyData.Copy
Set Addme = ws2.Range("A1:M8000")
Addme.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

I paste the entire column from column A to column M. I need to Copy and PasteSpecial only the cells from the worksheet ws1 that have values to the worksheet ws2. Then if I click again in the button and select another Workbook add the values to ws2 and not overwrite them. How can I do this in Visual Basic? What I'm missing here? Please guys, I really, really need your help! Thanks in advance.

SOLVED!

Just changed the code above to:

```
With ws2
    'Presuming the column "A" in ws2 will always contain the last row.
    intLastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Presuming we will ALWAYS copy the "A1:M8000" range, and that the column "A" is filled.
    'Because we determine the last used row based on this column in ws2 (intLastRow)
    ws1.Range("A1:M8000").Copy
    .Cells(intLastRow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
```

And added in the variables declaration this:

```
Dim intLastRow As Integer
```

Comment: By "Then if I click again in the button and select another Workbook add the values to ws2 and not overwrite them." you mean that in the same range they should be added together (e.g. in ws2 "A1" = 5, you clicked the button and now the "A1" = 5 + new value) **or** you want to paste the new values at the bottom of the already filled range in ws2?

Comment: I want to paste the new values at the bottom of the already filled range in ws2, mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the copy code with this :

```
Dim intLastRow As Integer 'put it where you declare variables.
'Maybe use long, if data on ws2 can exceed 32K rows or something like that.

With ws2
    'Presuming the column "A" in ws2 will always contain the last row.
    intLastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Presuming we will ALWAYS copy the "A1:M8000" range, and that the column "A" is filled.
    'Because we determine the last used row based on this column in ws2 (intLastRow)
    .Range(.Cells(intLastRow + 1, 1), .Cells(intLastRow + 1, 13)) = ws1.Range("A1:M8000").Value
End With
```

### Edit 1

Ammended the code based on comment from OP. Now with the correct `Range("A1:M8000")` and `Cells(intLastRow + 1, 13)`

### Edit 2

```
With ws2
    'Presuming the column "A" in ws2 will always contain the last row.
    intLastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Presuming we will ALWAYS copy the "A1:M8000" range, and that the column "A" is filled.
    'Because we determine the last used row based on this column in ws2 (intLastRow)
    ws1.Range("A1:M8000").Copy
    .Cells(intLastRow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
```

Comment: I will try this, but I have a question: why using Range("B1:M8000").Value
and not Range("A1:M8000").Value?

Comment: Lol, my mistake, sorry. I thought I have that copied from your code. But you can use `Range("A1:M8000")` of course. That was for my testing case.

Comment: I tested it and this code only copies the first line.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use "For" method to read each cells individually
The code below will copy from sheet1 only if the cell is not empty and will only paste if the cell in sheet2 is not filled

```
'this one will run each row    
For i = 1 to 8000 
     'this one will run each column
     For j = 1 to 13
          If ws1.cells(i,j) <> "" then
               ws1.cells(i,j).copy

          if ws2.cells(i,j) = "" then
               ws2.cells(i,j).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

          Else:
               cutcopymode=false

          End if 
          End if
     Next
Next
```

Comment: I'll try this solution and report if it worked, thanks mate :)

Comment: @user3664117 But accoding to what i read you will need to edit the code since the one i gave you will only paste the value if the destiny cell is empty, what you want is to paste bellow the one that is already there to do so you will need to put a condition to the i counter so he wont always begin on row 1 but to start on 8001 if you have already done the process once and on 16001 if you've done it twice, is that what you want?

Comment: I put the 8000 number becouse it exceeds always the amount of values in the Worksheet that I import the data. I've that solution becouse I don't really know from advance how much values does the Worsheet ws1 have. The final solution would be extract the data from ws1 to the bottom, then when I import the data from another similiar Worksheet the new data goes to the bottom of the first one and so on.

Comment: @user3664117 if it works for you than great =] just mark the answer as correct pls